# How to parse JSON string with object type of Map in Android?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I'm trying to parse this public Api JSON "https://api.quarantine.country/api/v1/summary/latest"
and the problem starts when I need to parse Object "Region" which is a Map of key String value Object Country. I'm doing this manually on purpose just for practice.
This is my code till now:

```
  private fun writeData(json: String?) {

        val jsonObj = JSONObject(json)


        val data = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data")
        val summary = data.getJSONObject("summary")
        val total_casesSummary = summary.getInt("total_cases")
        val active_casesSummary = summary.getInt("active_cases")
        val deathsSummary = summary.getInt("deaths")
        val recoveredSummary = summary.getInt("recovered")
        val criticalSummary = summary.getInt("critical")
        val testedSummary = summary.getInt("tested")
        val death_ratioSummary = summary.getDouble("death_ratio")
        val recovery_ratioSummary = summary.getDouble("recovery_ratio")

        val summaryObj = ChangeSummary(total_casesSummary,
            active_casesSummary,
            deathsSummary,
            recoveredSummary,
            criticalSummary,
            testedSummary,
            death_ratioSummary,
            recovery_ratioSummary)

        val change = data.getJSONObject("change")
        val total_casesChange = data.getInt("total_cases")
        val active_casesChange = data.getInt("active_cases")
        val deathsChange = data.getInt("deaths")
        val recoveredChange = data.getInt("recovered")
        val criticalChange = data.getInt("critical")
        val testedChange = data.getInt("tested")
        val death_ratioChange = data.getDouble("death_ratio")
        val recovery_ratioChange = data.getDouble("recovery_ratio")

        val changeObj = ChangeSummary(total_casesChange,
            active_casesChange,
            deathsChange,
            recoveredChange,
            criticalChange,
            testedChange,
            death_ratioChange,
            recovery_ratioChange)

        val regions = data.getJSONObject("regions")



    }
```

and there problem starts here when I need to read countries from object regions:

```
"regions":{
         "usa":{
            "name":"USA",
            "iso3166a2":"US",
            "iso3166a3":"USA",
            "iso3166numeric":"",
            "total_cases":34219271,
            "active_cases":5440268,
            "deaths":612532,
            "recovered":28166471,
            "critical":5259,
            "tested":487505878,
            "death_ratio":0.017900205997959454,
            "recovery_ratio":0.8231172136893273,
            "change":{
               "total_cases":10304,
               "active_cases":-36393,
               "deaths":179,
               "recovered":46518,
               "death_ratio":-1.5913145237633763e-7,
               "recovery_ratio":0.0011118897635858938
            }
         },
         "india":{
            "name":"India",
            "iso3166a2":"IN",
            "iso3166a3":"IND",
            "iso3166numeric":"",
            "total_cases":28996949,
            "active_cases":1308806,
            "deaths":351344,
            "recovered":27336799,
            "critical":8944,
            "tested":366334111,
            "death_ratio":0.01211658509314204,
            "recovery_ratio":0.9427474249101173,
            "change":{
               "total_cases":87345,
               "active_cases":-100842,
               "deaths":2115,
               "recovered":186072,
               "death_ratio":3.655106707928235e-5,
               "recovery_ratio":0.0035880023182339738
            }
         },
```

Comment: I won't get into argument as to why you're manually manipulating JSONObject instead of using one of many deserializing libraries but what you're looking at is considered a map which unlike an array has a key identifying each value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I m practicing manually to parse JSON.